# How do I sort a file and output the latest record in case duplicates exist?

Tags: awk, sort

I save all the requests, received via API, in a file. I wish to process only the latest request if duplicate requests arrive.

Sort command is not helping, I am using :

```
sort -r -k 1.69,1.88 ./InputFile | sort -k 1.70,1.88 -u   > ./sortedReqFile
```

The idea is to reverse the file and get the unique out of it, but it gives the same result as a direct sort -u on the input file.

Comment: Can you please give an example input and what your desired output is? We have no idea how the data looks like.

Comment: @chaos Its a fixed format file, where I am defining a key to the sort command. I understand that why sort -u on the original input and the reversed input file will be the same, however I am not clear on how can i achieve this in Unix. Maybe I will need to use awk or sed.

Comment: your best bet is `tac ./InputFile | sort -k 1.69,1.88 -u`

Comment: @1_CR tac is not supported in the OS and moreover, inverting the file is not helping in case I am using the sort command.

Answer (score 0):

just a wild guess

```
 awk '{A[substr($0,69,88)]=$0 ; } END { for ( b in A ) print A[b] ;}' InputFile |
 sort -k 1.70,1.88 -u   > sortedReqFile
```

- awk will keep last occurence of lines with the same 69-88 range char.
- `b` is use as an index for the array `A`.
- there is no need for `./` in front of data files.

The question you asked

> why sort -u give same result if I invert the file ?

The main point is that your first sort didn't alter any line, and is useless with regard to final sort command. If they don't alter or remove line, you can have any number of `sort`, `tac` between.

Suppose you sort a file with `H E L L O W O R L D` letter (each in a line)

- sort file : `D E H L L L O O R W`
- sort -r file : `W R O O L L L H E D`
- sort -r file | sort -u : `D E H L O R W`
- sort -u file : `D E H L O R W`

Comment: I sampled the command with the input i had, however i faced 2 issues:
1. The input file record is more than 3000 bytes ($0).
2. The output is same as before.